# asp.net: how do i prevent users from posting the same data multiple times

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, post, submit

i have a little asp.net web application.

it is a front end to a sql-server-2008 database.

after they fill out all the data, they will press submit and the data will be sent to the database.

after this point if the user refreshes the page, the data is posted again!!! how do i disable this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by the last request being a POST request to the page, what do you need to do is a redirect so the last request becomes a GET.

After you have handled the post data you can just do a redirect to the same page with:

```
Response.Redirect("~/ThePage.aspx");
```

This will prevent you from presenting a message to the user straight from the code behind, if you want to present a success message using this method you will need to add a querystring or something similar:

```
Response.Redirect("~/ThePage.aspx?result=success");
```

And then check on the page bind if the querystring to present a success message is set, such a check could look something like this:

```
if (Request.QueryString["result"] != null && Request.QueryString["result"].ToString().ToLower() == "success")
{
    //Show success message
}
```

Another solution which probably is superior but might require some more work is to wrap the form in a updatepanel, you can read more about it here: http://ajax.net-tutorials.com/controls/updatepanel-control/

An updatepanel will make the form submit with AJAX instead of full postback.

Comment: first part works awesoem!!!! can you tell me how woudl i check the page bind for "Success" ?

Comment: Added the check, you have to decide how to show the message yourself. :)

Comment: thanks so much. it works!!! the thing is though when i reload the page it will display the succesful message every time, is there a way to get it to display it only once?

Comment: You could add some kind of notification system in your sessions, but I think that is a bit out of line for this question.

Answer (score 4):

Send a Location header back to the user that redirects the browser to another page: refresh will then reload that other page rather than resubmit the old form.

Answer (score 2):

You need to follow the Post/Redirect/Get pattern which is explained on [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) and alluded to by Femi. In your code after you've done your processing do a `Response.Redirect` to the desired page.

Answer (score 2):

See this article about the PRG pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

In short, after the user POSTs (submits) data to your server, you issue a Response.Redirect to have the users browser GET a page. This way, if the user presses the reload button, it is the GET request that is repeated.